# Get driver of running browser

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I have a link in my app that is opened in chrome.

I want to write an automated test to check that the URL is correct.

So I need from my test to get the driver of the open browser (for simplicity, start with Chrome) in order to get the opened url.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try using chromium.exe as your chrome driver

Comment: do you want to open in browser or in mobile?

Comment: @HelpingHands on the mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can open website in android mobile device using below code :

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;

public class Openweb
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void openurl() throws Exception{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");// Replace your device platform version
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5");//Replace your device name
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "XXXXXXXXXX");//Replace your device udid
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", MobileBrowserType.BROWSER);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check the current link address.

String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

Hope this helps.